# Sharepoint Communications Site Specs

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am setting up a sharepoint communication site and I want to add some images that are just text. Is there a resource out there that provides the image size requirements for the hero images on the homepage, as well as for the header images on the sup-pages?

Thank you!